# Does PostgreSQL support Type 2 JDBC Driver?

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL support Type 2 JDBC Driver ?

I could only found Type 4 driver in there documentation.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, no [Type 2 ("native library wrapper")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_2_Driver_-_Native-API_Driver) JDBC driver for PostgreSQL.

One could be developed as a wrapper around `libpq`, much as `psycopg2` is for Python, but nobody's done the work for it. There'd be a lot of ugly hacking around with `JNA` or (worse) `JNI` for what I can't see as offering much benefit.

[Type 4 (native Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_4_Driver_-_Database-Protocol_Driver.28Pure_Java_Driver.29) JDBC drivers are generally superior. Why do you want a Type 2 driver?

Perhaps one of the third party vendors like [Progress](http://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/jdbc-drivers/data-sources/postgresql) has one, or something similar that meets your needs. Beware of their "Type 5" JDBC driver claims though - there's a lot of marketing guff in there, and while the claims may bear out there just isn't much substance to what's published in their comparison page, etc.

Comment: I am evaluating several RDBMS for my project. One criteria is to have type 2 driver for better performance.

Comment: By the way, there are at least two open-source projects for Postgres Type 4 (pure Java) JDBC drivers: (a) the [classic project](http://jdbc.postgresql.org) with much backward compatibility, and (b) the [next-generation project](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) with a fresh code base for the recent versions of Postgres and Java.

Comment: @Viraj ... then you need to go and adjust those criteria. If performance is a requirement, *measure performance*. Don't assume a type 2 driver will be magically faster. There are lots of reasons it could be slower too, actually.

Comment: @Viraj if you want performance, you should make your criterion be performance. Not some ham-fisted mythology about what is likely to lead to good performance.